# Clothes Washer Has Intermittent, Erratic Water Flow When Filling

Tags: water, appliances, washing-machine

My clothes washer has intermittent, erratic water flow when filling.  This issue started about one mounth ago.

It sometimes makes a screeching noise and the water flow sputters as it approaches the fill level.  The schreeching starts at about 57% full and the sputtering starts at about 70% full.

This only happens when filing with cold water, not with hot water and not with a mix of cold and hot water.

If I turn on water at nearby faucet, the water returns to normal flow and the noise stops.  The water flow stops at the proper level, and the agitation starts properly.

If I switch to a lower fill level setting, the water flow and noise stop, and the agitation starts.

I blew out the air tube to the level control switch but that did fix the issue.

I am using city utility water.
Edit: Water pressure does not seem abnormally high or low :End

Kenmore Model 110 27802690
EDIT: Purchased new 1996  :END

[image: wire diagram]

Has anyone had a similar experience?

I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Check your water pressure

Comment: Need the age of the machine.  Was it new or used when you acquired it?